# Test for convergence/divergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given the series

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4}.$$

I need to test for convergence/divergence. I can compare this to the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}$, which diverges.

To use the comparison test, won't I need to show that $\frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4}>\frac{k^3}{k^4}=\frac{1}{k}$, in order to state the original series diverges?
This doesn't seem to hold, I feel like I'm missing the obvious.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: But the series indeed diverges. You can do the limit comparison test with the harmonic series. That's very easy

Comment: make this an answer.

Comment: @imranfat Yeah, that's right. But how come the comparison test doesn't work?

Comment: I am not saying that the comparison test would not work. But then you need to show that the given series is (ultimately) greater than the harmonic series for some k and beyond. That's not so easy, particularly because the denominator has a plus sign. When you have a given series consisting of a rational fraction, i.e. polynomial over polynomial, then the difference of their degrees is what you should compare it with. That tells you convergence/divergence. The limit comparison test will give you a finite limit L, hence the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For $k\ge3$,
$$
\frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4}\ge\frac1{k+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

When $k \geq 1$, we have $k^3+4 \leq k^3+4k^3 = 5k^3$ (Since $4 \leq 4k^3$ for $k \geq 1$). Also, when $k \geq 2$, we have $k^2-1 > \frac{k^2}{2}$ (This is again straightforward to verify, equality happens when $k = \sqrt{2}$ :)). Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4} = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4} \geq \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\frac{k^2}{2}}{5k^3} = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k}.$$
The lower bound is the harmonic series that clearly diverges. Hence the original series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

To show that the given series is (ultimately) greater than the harmonic series for some k and beyond, We could consider this limit:

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{\frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4}} = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{k^3+4}{k^3-k}= 1$$

Hence, by the definition of limit,
$$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\exists N\gt0,\text{such that} ~k \gt N,~~~~~\left|\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{\frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4}} - 1 \right| \lt \varepsilon$$
Let $\varepsilon = 1$, for $k \gt N$, we have

\begin{align*}
\ \left|\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{\frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4}} - 1\right| \lt 1\rightarrow 0 \lt \frac{\frac{1}{k}}{\frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4}} \lt 2 \rightarrow \frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4} \gt \frac{1}{2k}\rightarrow \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4} \gt \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k} \space\space\space\text{(for k > N)}
\end{align*}
Since the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k}$ is divergent,by the comparison test, $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2-1}{k^3+4}$ is divergent

Answer (score 0):

If you use the limit comparison test instead, and compare it with the harmonic series, you will find for the limit L=1 ($k^3/k^3$), since the harmonic series diverges, so does your given series